# .htaccess replace (rewrite) $_GET variables in PHP URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, url-rewriting

I have a URL that will be something like `example.com/index.php?p=test` so that the PHP will load the test variable using `$_GET['p']`. The URL can already be simplified to `example.com?p=test`; however, I wish to simplify this in my `.htaccess` to `site.com/test`. How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Place the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# The two lines below allow access to existing files on your server, bypassing
# the rewrite

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

You can then access `whatever` from `example.com/whatever` like the following:

```
$value = $_GET['p']; // "whatever"
```

Comment: I have other files on my server though, using this doesn't allow me to access any of them. For instance, i have site.com/forum, which this breaks :( any way I could possibly have it work ONLY on the root, and only if the directory doesn't already exist?

Comment: @hetoan2: I've updated my answer to hopefully help you out with that.

Comment: thanks that fixed my directory issue, but I can't seem to access the files from example.com/whatever when i enter it. only when i enter example.com/index.php?p=whatever will it rewrite the url as example.com/whatever

Comment: @heotan2: The files must exist/not exist (depending on what you're trying). The above `.htaccess` should only rewrite to the `index.php` if the URL specified is not a file/directory on your server.

Comment: would you mind telling me how to turn `example.com/test` into `example.com/?p=test`; given that `example.com/test` is not already a directory on the server?

Comment: @hetoan2: My answer does just that.

Comment: its giving me 500 internal server errors :( I have no idea why.

Comment: turned out to be an issue with wordpress. thanks for all your help :D