# Rewrite a URL variable into an HTML file

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've seen many cases of these rewrite questions but I don't get all the regular experessions and browser errors and such so I was hoping that someone could help me.

Ok, so I have a file with a url variable 'pages.php?p=foo' and I would like to rewrite it so that it appears as 'foo.html' in the same directory.

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule (.+).html pages.php?p=$1
```

The trouble is, the browser displays 400 Bad Request errors.

I'm hoping there's a fix for this but I can't get my head around it.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Here is a link to a question like yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462359/htaccess-replace-rewrite-get-variables-in-php-url

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 RewriteRule (.*)\.html pages.php?p=$1
```

Comment: The only thing is it breaks every html file in subsequent directories.