# PHP `$_GET` variables without the `?id=`

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a page called event.php where a `$_GET` variable is passed in like this: `/event?id=1` (I have used my .htaccess to remove the `.php` extension). Is there a way, presumably using .htaccess file, that I can make it so the url is `/event/1` instead of `/event?id=1`?

Comment: This attitude is called URL Segmentes, should help you in your search.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462359/htaccess-replace-rewrite-get-variables-in-php-url?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't know what to search for.